# React Native custom activity

Tags: react-native

I need custom onCreate, onResume, onPause ... in ReactActivity. How can I make it correct?

I write this code, but my code won't launch and my custom plugin not registred (if i comment onCreate, onPause, so my custom plugin work good):

```
package com.myapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //my code here
    }
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "MyApp";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //and my code here
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.